# OpenVas remediation cipher suites

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, ciphers, openvas

This is my first time running a vulnerability scan software like OpenVas. It is really a great tool to found out about vulnerabilities in the network.
I have found difficult to troubleshoot the vulnerabilities related to weak cipher suites and protocols. For example, the OpenVas reports:

```
2.6.2 Medium 48004/tcp
Medium (CVSS: 4.3)
NVT: SSL/TLS: SSLv3 Protocol CBC Cipher Suites Information Disclosure Vulnerability (POODLE)

Summary
This host is prone to an information disclosure vulnerability.
```

However, when I scan the same server with Qualys SSL Labs online test, I get:

```
Protocols
TLS 1.3 No
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3   No
SSL 2   No
For TLS 1.3 tests, we currently support draft version 18.
```

I remember using IISCrypto in this machine to disable obsolete protocols and cipher suites.

Can a server have cipher suites enable/disable in some ports?  Can my Windows Server have SSL3 enable in port 48004, but disable on port 443?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I remember ssl labs refuses non 443 port scans. Try a fry account over at sslping.com. Or try scanning with testssl.sh.

Comment: You can also try scanning it yourself with nmap.  nmap -sV --unprivileged --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 48004 hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a server have cipher suites enable/disable in some ports? Can my Windows Server have SSL3 enable in port 48004, but disable on port 443?

Yes. The actual application bound to a specific port may be different or may have a different configuration. For example, you could run `apache` on 443 and `nginx` on port 8000. You may be running some other app or DB which has a web service on 48004, possibly [nimbusdb](http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/48004).

I would check what app is actually running and see what webserver application is actually being used and how to properly configure it.

As @StackzOfZtuff noted in his comments, Qualys is only scanning 443 and does not scan other ports, so its not telling you anything about port 48004.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Does that means that when IIS Crypto changes the values in the registry of the server it only affects port 443 and NOT the entire server?
  
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL

Comment: I do not use the too, but from a quick review of their docs I believe it only affects IIS. If IIS is not running on the other ports, it would not impact those ports- IIS is not necessarily a proxy or gateway before other web servers your system may run.